# How to make an image always the size (or bigger) than the browser window, and stuck to a certain point

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to know how to make an image rescale accordingly with the size of the browser window, similar to how [these](http://whiteboard.is) guys have their background video on the main page. I have something similar working for a video, but applying the same code on the image just won't work.

Having both the `width` and `height` of the image on `100%` is not acceptable, since that will put the image out of proportions.

All help greatly appreciated!

**Please note** that it is downright impossible for me to add a jsfiddle here, because in that case I would have to put my entire project in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No JavaScript required.

You can do this using the various `background` CSS properties, namely `background-size:cover;` and `background-position:center center;` on an element with 100% dimensions, which will fill the browser if these are also defined for `html` and `body` and the element is a direct child.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/qA4CH/)

```
html, body, #img{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#img{
  background-image:url(myImage.png);
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center center;
}
```

Comment: While this is what I am looking for, it somehow disables me to use `display:none;` for `#img`. I must be able to somehow hide or stop displaying the div or image. Do you know how to still be able to use `display:none;`, or do you know any alternatives?

Comment: @TobyvanKempen - its not terribly clear what you'er after, or why changing display wouldnt work- without more of your code, it may be impossible to say either way

Comment: @TobyvanKempen - `display:none` should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/qA4CH/1/

Comment: I noticed that using `z-index:value;` works. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

if it's a background image (like in the example link), you can use:

```
background-size: cover;
```

Else if the img is in the HTML, you can give it a width of 100% indeed, but set the height to auto so it scales normally.

```
width: 100%;
height: auto
```